# C# Button is firing only on the second click

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have done a simple windows form. My button is firing only on the second click. Why is that ?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //button1.Enabled = false; will disable the button before the event is fired
    this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.dosomething);
}

private void dosomething(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("Initializing :" + cart + "...");
    this.button1.Click -= new System.EventHandler(this.dosomething);
}
```

Can some one explain this.

Comment: why not call doSomething directly on button1_Click

Comment: sorry that wasn't snmpconn. that was dosomething in the -= eventhandler

Comment: it still doesn't work on the firs click. It only works on the secondclick

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As other said you hook up the event only on the first click.

Place this line in the form_load event

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.dosomething);
```

Comment: Perfect works. Thank you. I'm just a beginner in windows forms so might ask some more stupid questions.

Comment: that's all right. we all need to start some where. you could have called `this.dosomething` directly in the `button1_Click` Also please mark an answer if you are done with this question

Answer (score 10):

That's exactly what you told it to do.

```
   this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.dosomething);
```

This line adds a handler to the click event, which will run for all future clicks.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're hooking it up on the first click:

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.dosomething);
```

so it's going to take at least one click to get the `dosomething` method to fire.

One other problem with this approach is that you could end up hooking this event handler up more than once if an exception is thrown. I know you're removing it in the `dosomething` event, but it would really be better to just hookup this event in the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is to remove the bound event from the button after the button was clicked. You can call the event directly by:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dosomething(null, null)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want button to work only 1 time, you can unsuscribe to click event.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething();
    button1.Click -= button1_Click;
}
```